# How we can add a prject as a library in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

How we can enable Google play library in android studio and how we can add all my library in project and we can import these lib in my working space?

Comment: Follow http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html

Comment: thank you Raghunandan ,can you please tell me how we can add a project as a library like facebook sdk,actionbar sherlock and others..in android studio\

Comment: there is an option in android studio to import a module. You can check that option from file --> import module

Answer (score 0):

You can use the grade file build.grade to include it directly as a dependency.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.+'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'android'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 17
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.actionbarsherlock:actionbarsherlock:4.4.0@aar'
}
```